# Visualforce and Console Integration Toolkit results in Cross-Origin Framing error

Tags: visualforce, javascript, cross-domain, custom-console-components, consoleintegrationtoolkit

I'm working on an App-level console component that has links in it. Those links should open new tabs (preferably in the console layout, but a new browser tab works as well) not on the Salesforce domain.

I am able to get the new console tab to open via openPrimaryTab(), and it references the correct URL, and I have that URL whitelisted.

The problem is no content is rendered. In my browser's developer tools console, I see it's due to Cross-Origin Framing.

I've found this [SE article](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5009/open-a-service-console-primary-tab-from-a-custom-component-module) which helped get me to where I am currently and referenced this exact issue in the answer, but no resolution as it was not the main focus of the question.

Is there anyway to allow an external link in an App level console component to open a primary tab (in the Service Cloud Console)? If there isn't why does the [openPrimaryTab()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_console/Content/sforce_api_console_openprimarytab.htm) method state external URLs can be opened if added to the console's whitelist - would that only be relevant for API or Apex integrations?

> Note that users can open an external URL if it has been added to the console’s whitelist. For more information, see “Whitelist Domains for a Salesforce Console” in the online help.

If this function is limited to Apex, would I have to/can I create a custom controller to call the openPrimaryTab method that is triggered by the an onClick attribute in the visualforce page?

Comment: For now, I'm using the `window.open(url,'_blank')` javascript to open in a window outside of the console.