# Access to parent element from Visualforce page with javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, cors

I'm trying to access to an element located in an Standard Page with Jquery from my visualforce embedded.

There's a way to have access to those elements, now I'm getting an error like:

"Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin"?

Comment: Visualforce pages are served from a different domain than standard pages. Its there to prevent [Cross Site Scripting](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Scripting). You may also want to take a look at [this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/why-are-visualforce-pages-served-from-a-different-domain).

Answer (score 2):

This is blocked by the browser because of the [Same Origin Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). The embedded VF page in the `iframe` cannot interact with its parent page because it is served from a different domain than a standard page.

`https://*.salesforce.com` vs `https://*.visual.force.com`

You will need to find another way to accomplish your goal. You might need to resort to creating a VF page that mimics the design of the standard page using the `<apex:sectionHeader>`, `<apex:detail>` and `<apex:relatedList>` tags.