# Using Console Integration Toolkit in VisualForce in Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning, console

I have a Visualforce page that is used inside the lightning console app. According to this [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_classic_bridge_methods.htm#sforce_api_console_lightning_classic_bridge_methods), certain methods from Console Integration Toolkit are permissible in Lightning. However, when I attempt to use the [closeTab()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_closetab.htm#sforce_api_console_closetab) method, for instance, I encounter the following error:

> iframeinterface.js:1 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with
> origin
> "https://business-enterprise-326-dev-ed.scratch.my.salesforce.com"
> from accessing a cross-origin frame.

I suspect this error arises because Visualforce pages are served from a [different domain](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/why-are-visualforce-pages-served-from-a-different-domain). Is there a way to use the Console Integration Toolkit within a Visualforce page rendered in a Lightning console app?

Comment: Did you try adding the Visualforce domain to [CORS](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.extend_code_cors.htm&language=en_US&type=5)? That may fix your problem.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, it didn't fix the issue

Comment: it is clearly a CORS issue .. are you adding the root domain or subdomain.. be careful